# Send JSON data to server from react without rerender the page

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, tornado

I'm a bit new to ReactJS,

I've created a simple form and table, each time I hit the submit the state of the table change with the new data.

I'm using tornado as a backend server and mongodb as my DB.

I'm looking for a way to send the same JSON to the server on a second pipe (without rerendering the page again.)

How can I do it?

---- edit - react component -----

```
import Re

act from 'react';

export default class Reblaze_Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onNewUser = this.onNewUser.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            data: window.obj,
        };
    }

    onNewUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = {};
        for (const field in this.refs) {
            formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
        }

        this.state.data.push(formData);
        this.setState({
            data: this.state.data,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
                <div>
                    <h2>Dashboard page</h2>

                    <form onSubmit={this.onNewUser}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="first-name-input">First name:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="firstname" id="first-name-input" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="last-name-input">Last name:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="lastname" id="last-name-input" />
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                    </form>

                    <br /><br />

                    <div className="table-responsive">
                        <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h4>First name</h4></td>
                                    <td><h4>Last name</h4></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.data.map((line, key) => 
                                    <tr key={key}>
                                        <td>{line.firstname}</td>
                                        <td>{line.lastname}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )}
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us your client side React component?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: I've added the react component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're submitting form data and immediately updating table without checking if your data reaches the server. This way it is possible to update user view while failing to update the database.

I strongly recommend to use some promise-based HTTP-client like Axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). Send some request, then wait for the promise resolve, and only after that update your component state.

You need something like this:

```
import React from 'react';  
import axios from 'axios';

/*...*/

onNewUser(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = {};
  for (const field in this.refs) {
    formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
  }

  axios.post('yourApiUrl', formData)
  // if request is sent and status is ok, update form and send second request
  .then((res) => {
    this.state.data.push(formData);
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data,
    });
    return axios.post('yourApiUrl', formData);
  })
  // if second request is ok, receive a notification 
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('second request is ok');
  })
  // if there is an error, receive a notification
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}

/*...*/
```

Comment: do you have a simple example on how to use Axios in my case?

Comment: and how do I access the data from my server side?

I'm creating a class with my api for the relevant url, and in it a post function and now I want to get the data so i'll be able to insert it to my db. but how?

Comment: @ElonSalfati: I'd recommend to start from the beginning. First, React/Redux manual:
http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-simple-crud-app-with-react-redux-part-1/#table-of-contents

Comment: @ElonSalfati: Then, any manuals for your backend environment. No offense, but your question seems to me more like "How to make a functional web app", which is much more complicated question than just editing some React code.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to make the basic responses from react to tornado, but I'll read the manual you gave me, thanks

Comment: @ElonSalfati: axios.post('yourApiUrl', formData) sends a POST request to yourApiUrl with formData as request body. After request reaches your API, you need to parse request body with some backend function, and then update your Mongo collection with that data.